# erro ao zerar uma string

Tags: c

estou em um problema no meu código em que quando zero a string e adiciono novas palavras  ela apenas armazena a primeira parte.[image: Como pode ser visto na imagem, primeiramente estava armazenando normalmente, depois só armazena a primeira palavra]

código segue abaixo:

```
printf("Digite o nome do seu laboratorio:\n");

gets(nome_lab);

printf("O nome do laboratorio eh: %s.\n", nome_lab);

printf("Digite 1 para continuar e 2 para alterar o nome.\n");

scanf("%d", &x);

if(x == 1) printf("Vamos continuar");
if(x == 2) {
    printf("Digite o nome do laboratorio.\n");
    strcpy(nome_lab,"");
    scanf("%s", nome_lab);
    };
if(x!= 1 && x!= 2){
printf("Digite um numero valido.\n");
printf("Digite 1 para continuar e 2 para alterar o nome.\n");
while(x!= 1 || x!= 2){ scanf("%d", &x);
printf("Digite um numero valido.\n");
printf("Digite 1 para continuar e 2 para alterar o nome.\n");
 }
};

printf("%s", nome_lab);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é um erro! O problema é no:

```
scanf("%s", nome_lab);
```

Você está utilizando o `%s`, ele só guarda até o primeiro espaço em branco, ou seja, se você tem strings com espaços em branco, melhor não usa-lo.

Tente dessa maneira:

```
gets(nome_lab);
```

Comment: Entendi, mas quando uso o gets o programa termina sem eu poder escrever, no caso aparece seguinte mensagem no prompt "process returned 0"

Comment: limpe os buffers antes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente :)